# Parse HTML doc with HtmlAgilityPack-Xpath, RegExp

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I try parse image url from html with HtmlAgilityPack.  In html doc I have img tag :

```
<a class="css_foto" href="" title="Fotka: MyKe015">
   <span>
      <img src="http://213.215.107.125/fotky/1358/93/v_13589304.jpg?v=6" 
           width="176" height="216" alt="Fotka: MyKe015" />
   </span>
</a>
```

I need get from this img tag atribute src. I need this: **http://213.215.107.125/fotky/1358/93/v_13589304.jpg?v=6.**

I know this:

1. Src atribute consist url, url start
   with
   **http://213.215.107.125/fotky**
2. I know value of alt atribute Url
   have
       variable lenght and also html doc
       consist other img tags with url, which start with
       **http://213.215.107.125/fotky**
3. I know alt attribute of img tag (Fotka: Myke015))

Any advance, I try many ways, but nothing works good.

Last I try this:

```
    List<string> src;

    var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://pokec.azet.sk/myke015");
    req.Method = "GET";

    using (WebResponse odpoved = req.GetResponse())
    {
        var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.Load(odpoved.GetResponseStream());

        var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]");
        src = new List<string>(nodes.Count);

        if (nodes != null)
        {
            foreach (var node in nodes)
            {
                if (node.Id != null)
                    src.Add(node.Id);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your XPath selects the `img` nodes, not the `src` attributes belonging to them.

Instead of (selecting all image tags that have a `src` attribute):

```
var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]");
```

Use this (select the `src` attributes that are child nodes of all `img` elements):

```
var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img/@src");
```

Comment: Oded, how can I specify in Xpath value of src atribute. src="Fotka: miky015"

Comment: @Lucas - at this point, you can use `node.InnerText` to get the value.

Comment: Oded I use your advace, but I get error: '//img@src' has an invalid token, if I used your Xpath exp "//img@src".

Comment: @Lucas - apologies, I missed a `/`. It should be `//img/@src`.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath 1.0 expression:

```
//a[@alt='Fotka: MyKe015']/@src
```